# Is there a way to fix "multi-page selection with headers or footers" in PDF using Adobe's Reader?

Tags: pdf-reader, selection

If you have some text document with headers and/or footers like ODF in LibreOffice Writer, you can select a block of text across page boundaries without a problem.

Example:

[image: Selection crossing page boundaries with footer line in LibreOffice Writer (ODF)]

However if you export that document to PDF, opening it in Adobe's Reader, then trying to select a block of text across page boundaries would also include the headers and footers.

Example:

[image: Selection crossing page boundaries with footer line in Adobe Acrobat (PDF)]

That is true even if you manually add "article frames" that mark the actual text blocks making up the "article".
So I wonder whether that might be a bug in Adobe's Reader (I was using Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017 (2017.012.30229) for the test).

Anyway is there a user-friendly solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: No you can't fix it in Adobe reader.

### Long answer:

OK, so PDF is short for "Portable Document Format" and the document it contains is standardised to a certain ISO format.  When creating a PDF, there are guidelines the document has to conform to, to ensure that it is a compatible and valid PDF file.  To be a format that is "everything to everyone" there are definite limitations to what is and isn't supported *as standard*.  When a PDF is created from any application, it gets converted into a standard PDF format - however, the rules for converting it will vary between different applications, although the resulting PDF should always conform to ISO standards.

While a PDF is standardised, it's also important to know that any application can add their own custom data to a PDF file.  Other applications can read this data, but *probably* only the creator application knows what to do with the data.

So LibreOffice Writer will create the PDF and probably adds custom tags to the header and footer elements.  If you import a PDF into LibreOffice, it could probably read back it's own custom tags and decide where the headers and footers are.  However, because they are *custom* tags, only LibreOffice knows what they mean.  PDF does have tags for marking headers and footers correctly, but the added complication of implementing it correctly may have meant the developers of LibreOffice simply didn't bother.

There are workarounds and possible ways to circumvent this, for instance by changing the text order within a page.  However you will need layer control for this, not a feature most document editors have.  Or you could add headers and footers as images and not text.

Comment: On "TL;DR": What exactly is long there?

Comment: I thought there is some standard adding "structure" to PDFs (for exactly the purpose I'm after). So maybe LibreOffice does not add the "correct structure" yet?
I cross-checked with a document created by Adobe InDesign 17.3 (assuming Adobe knows how to do things correctly): Still it also selects the footer lines with the block of text.

Comment: When you select text on a page, text is selected in order of the original layer order.  So you could try re arranging the layers - maybe put all the header and footer layers at the very bottom before you do the final export to PDF, it's not an answer but it might trick adobe reader into not selecting that text until you get to the bottom of the document.